# Python equivalent of join for QList c++

Tags: c++, python, qt

I am writing a simple text editor and I have a list of keywords which I define like this in Python:

```
keywords = [
   "action" ,
   "perform",
]
```

and like this in c++

```
#define {
    QList<QString> keywords
    keywords.append("action");
    keywords.append("perform");
}; // Is this correct? I am trying to create a constant that would be a list of keywords
```

In Python, I create a regular expression that matches a keyword like this:

```
keyword_match = r'\b(' + r'|'.join(keywords) + r')\b'
```

My question is, how can I get the same effect as "join" in c++.

Comment: It would be better if you described the desired functionality without referring to Qt so that people that know about Python but not Qt can help you.

Comment: Don't use `#define` for constants. Don't use it for anything unless you have to. And no, that isn't proper syntax.

Comment: @us2012 Essesntially in c++ I need a regular expression that will match any words from a list or array of keywords.

Comment: Side note: never use `'|'.join(seq)` when create a regex *unless* you are 100% sure that the elements of `seq` do not contain any regex's special character. If you are not 100% sure, use `re.escape`: `'|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in keywords)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `QStringList`, which has a `join()` method.